# Dual colour in one label in flex 3

Tags: flex3, flexbuilder

I was just wondering if you can get two colours in a label so i can have some of the text white and some red. I have been looking online and have not found anything. However, I though here would be a more appropriate place to ask. If not i will just use two labels. But any input is appreciated.
Regards
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt that's possible.